# Batch: How to find and get file name

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to find files which contains a `string` and print file names with and without extension.

Very important, files are located `sub-folders` of `main Folder`, I know only path of `main Folder`.

This returns 'full path' and extension of files containing word `string`:

```
findstr /s /m "string" c:main Folder\*.txt >list.txt
```

**Desired output: *only file name***

Cheers, Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /s /m /i "string" "c:main Folder\*.txt" ') DO (
 ECHO full    %%a
 ECHO name    %%~na
 ECHO nameext %%~nxa
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I added `/i` for case-insensitivity.

Choose the filename version you want and redirect at will.

Comment: Cheers Gents, both case are very useful.

Comment: @Andy - Be wary of the FINDSTR /S option - it is bugged. It might fail to find some files that match '"*.txt"' if there exist files named something like '"abc.txt2"'. See the section titled *"BUG - Short 8.3 filenames can break the /D and /S options"* at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/1012053 for more info.

Comment: @Magoo - Thanks, I will take in count this big.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /r "c:\main Folder" %%# in (*.txt) do @(find "string" "%%f#" >nul 2>&1 && echo %%~n#)>>list.txt
```

May be [FOR /R](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) is what you need?

Comment: @ npocmaka How I can output this to a text file?

Comment: @ npocmaka Sorry, maybe I miss something, but isn't creating even list.txt; Is it searching in sub-folders of 'main folder'?On other side, how I specify in *.txt files to search?